# log.d not working in Android services (Delphi Berlin)

Tags: android, delphi, service

I am using Delphi-Berlin Update-2

Android service cannot use log.d() because that requires uses FMX.Types, and using that will crash the entire app.

I tried to extract the log section out of FMX.Types but without success.

Is there any solution getting log.d to work?

So far I have been using IdUDP for that, but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Submit a bug report, if you think there is a defect in the libraries. Stack Overflow is not the developer of this product. If you think there is a defect in your code, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @David, see [RSP-16524](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16524),
I know SO is not the developer, but hoped someone might know a workaround.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the Emba engineers cannot reproduce your bug. When submitting a bug report you should include as many of the steps necessary to reproduce. I'd include a complete program, the simplest possible program. And I'd definitely include the details of the device you are using. Many issues with Delphi on mobile are related to specific devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Tokyo and seeing the same issue on a real LG-LS997 device.

You can use the built-in `LOGI` as so:

```
uses Androidapi.Log;

procedure MyProcedure(msg: String);
var
  M: TMarshaller;
begin
  LOGI(M.AsUtf8(msg).ToPointer);
end;
```

Further information:

Every time I include an FMX unit in my service, I get a segmentation fault. `Log.d` calls into `LOGI`, which calls the Android NDK function `__android_log_write`. There is also `__android_log_print` for formatting, but it hasn't been wrapped. You should probably just format within Delphi anyway and call `__android_log_write`.

`LOGI` is defined to call `__android_log_write` with logging level `ANDROID_LOG_INFO`. Warn, error, and fatal have also been wrapped as `LOGW`, `LOGE`, and `LOGF`.

I've wrapped the rest of the logging levels here (untested, and excluding `ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN`):

```
function LOGDEF(Text: MarshaledAString): Integer;
begin
  Result := __android_log_write(android_LogPriority.ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT, 'default', Text);
end;

function LOGV(Text: MarshaledAString): Integer;
begin
  Result := __android_log_write(android_LogPriority.ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, 'verbose', Text);
end;

function LOGDBG(Text: MarshaledAString): Integer;
begin
  Result := __android_log_write(android_LogPriority.ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, 'debug', Text);
end;

function LOGS(Text: MarshaledAString): Integer;
begin
  Result := __android_log_write(android_LogPriority.ANDROID_LOG_SILENT, 'silent', Text);
end;
```

Comment: Many thanks Milie ! Just tried it and it works perfectly. So even in Tokyo it wasn't fixed? I stopped Delphi subscription because some bugs and issues I have been filed were only addressed after 18+ months.

Comment: @JBart Yeah, still broken in Tokyo. I don't blame you. TEdit is still buggy as well. I'm just inflating Android views and using those.

Comment: Issue exists in Delphi 11.0.  I can't get log.d to work at all for Android.